# Фильтр в модели, ссылки на внешние ключи

Tags: python, django

Как зафильтровать модель и обратиться по внешним связям к атрибутам модели, например:

модель Reviews

```
  class Reviews(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    good=models.ForeignKey(Good)
    description=models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name=u'Общее впечатление')
    negative=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name=u'Недостатки')
    positive=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name=u'Достоинства')
    quantity_star=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    review_score=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_last_change=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    date_create=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

модель 2

```
class UserReg(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar=models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='users/')
```

фьюшка

```
args['reviews']=Reviews.objects.filter(good=id_good)
```

Как теперь в шаблоне `{{reviews.user.avatar}}` выполнить такой запрос
Тоесть через reviews через внешнюю связь с моделью `user` далее обратиться к модели `UserReg` к атрибуту avatar

Если вместо `filter` будет `get`, то все получится...

в шаблоне, так не получается при использовании filter

```
{% for rev in reviews %}
   {{rev.user.avatar}} # тут не получается вытащить avatar
{% endfor %}
```

при get все получится

```
{{reviews.user.avatar}}
```

Answer (score 1):

`objects.get()` работает, потому что вы получаете объект. `objects.filter()` возвращает объект `queryset`, который можно обойти в цикле:

```
{% for item in reviews %}
    <img src="{{ item.user.avatar.url }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

К слову о собственной модели юзера, лучше наследоваться от `AbstractBaseUser` и добавить этого юзера в `settings`, чем использовать `OneToOneField`

Comment: Я понимаю разницу между get и filter, дело в том, что как я писал выше обход в цикле не работает, т.е.  avatar не вытаскивается

Comment: @user208820 Уточняйте все подробности, что вам помогли быстрее.  Вообще изображение нужно помещать в тег `<img/>` и вызывать его `url`. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Не понимаю что не понятно....я уже писал, что не получается так...вы мне снова это же решение предлагаете, только поместили в img ответ